# How to control the width of ZPL alphanumeric code 128 barcode

Tags: zpl

I am printing a code 128 barcode in ZPL, which must be 78mm. The following numeric barcode works as expected:
^XA^FO141,330^BY3,3,^BCR,243,Y,N,N,A^FD12001752107481808006410360011596^FS^XZ

But changing one number to 'X' near the end of the barcode, means the barcode is now printed as 91mm:
^XA^FO141,330^BY3,3,^BCR,243,Y,N,N,A^FD1200175210748180800641036001X596^FS^XZ

Changing the barcode module with from 3 to 2 with ^BY2 makes the barcode 60mm which is not acceptable.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Code 128 has different [Subtypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128#Subtypes). One of them can encode two numbers in one barcode-character. Your Zebra optimizes your barcode because you use the

```
^BCo,h,f,g,e,m
```

Command with Parameter m = mode set to

> A = Automatic Mode
>
> This analyzes the data sent and automatically
> determines the best packing method. The full
> ASCII character set can be used in the ^FD
> statement — the printer determines when to shift
> subsets. A string of four or more numeric digits
> causes an automatic shift to Subset C.

Switching modes and printing alphanumeric makes your barcode longer.